# Hexo Next theme, the menu and title on header is not in a row

Tags: html, hexo

I'm using hexo Next theme, version is 5.1.4.

Mine is like this:
[image]

But most other pages which used the same theme displays title and header in a row:

[image]

I searched many information on Google but can't find a solution.

Comment: First image looks like you are opening it in mobile and second is in any large width device.
Theme will be mobile compatible. This is why it doesn't come in a row.

Comment: both of them opened with chrome on PC

Answer (score 1):

it's from different theme scheme. the first is `Muse`, the second is `Mist`.

you need to change the config `theme/next/_config.yml` as below:

```
scheme: Mist
```

Then do the following:

```
hexo clean
hexo deploy
```